# grails criteria 'has at least one'

Tags: grails, one-to-many

guys!
There are many Managers in one Organization. Manager - is a child of spring security SecUser class, that has many Authorities(in my case 'buyer','seller').
**I`d like to find organizations that have at least one manager with authority 'seller'**

```
    class Organization {
    ...
        static hasMany = [managers:Manager]
    }

    class Manager extends SecUser{
    ...
        Organization organization
    }
    class SecUser {
    ...
      Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
            SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this).collect { it.secRole } as Set
        }
    }
```

Criteria or hql - doesn`t matter. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'd be

```
Organization.executeQuery(
    "select distinct(ur.secUser.organization) " +
    "from SecUserSecRole ur " +
    "where ur.secRole.authority='seller'")
```